# Positioning of Intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I position a context hint? Something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFuaq.png]

below text using this code:

```
Point point = this.rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(rtb.SelectionStart);
        this.lb.Location = point;
```

Note code output above was the context hint or Intelliense will be beside the text typed in rtb. Not below because I make it in selection start, but I just want to add something like + "\n" so that it will be put below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, put this in the `KeyUp` event of the `RichTextBox`:

```
using (Graphics g = this.rtb.CreateGraphics()) {
    point.Y += (int)g.MeasureString("A", rtb.Font).Height + 10; // the 10 is padding
}
this.lb.Location = point;
```

This will measure the height of the font to calculate how far to move it.. then adds 10 for padding.

You may need some extra logic around this for bigger fonts though.

Comment: it goes below sir but when i type more words in rtb it stock in a location and dont move ...

Comment: You should be putting it in the `KeyUp` event of the `RichTextBox` so that it updates after every key press...

Comment: ill upload screenshot of current output

Comment: sir can it be automatic? while typing? i see it worked when i use keypress up but i doenst when its only inside textchanged event

Comment: No problem. Also, you might want to save the measurement of the font so you're not creating a new `Graphics` object each time a user presses a key.